# How to get tweets of specific location with specific hashtags

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-rest-api

I'm trying to collect tweets of last 7 days using Search REST API and Tweepy package in Python.

This is my code:

```
import tweepy

ACCESS_TOKEN = '?'
ACCESS_SECRET = '?'
CONSUMER_KEY = '?'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '?'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
api.wait_on_rate_limit = True
api.wait_on_rate_limit_notify = True

    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q='#newiphone OR #newappleproduct' , lang= 'en', geocode='43.8041,120.5542,20km').items():
        print tweet.created_at, tweet.text, tweet.user.id , tweet.user.followers_count
```

My problem is that, I can get any output from this code. However, when I remove the geocode='43.8041,120.5542,20km' it gives me results that I want.

Could someone please help me how to add geolocation to the search?

Comment: If you search your geocode value on google maps you get a location lost in China. It seems there are no cities near that point, so no tweets might come from there... Are you sure the latitude and longitude you are using are correct?

Comment: @CarlesMitjans I want the tweets related to Oregon state, when I search in google it gives me this "43.8041° N, 120.5542° W" that's why I added those latitude and longitude I also replace it with "43.755876,-121.569935,100km" which I checked in Google Map and it is a location in Oregon state but I do not get any output! 
Do you think it is related to my hashtags and my geocode and there is no problem on the implementation?

Comment: @CarlesMitjans You were correct I changed hashtags now it is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search query was correct! the problem was about tweets, there were no tweet with these specific hashtags